# context menu itemselect event

Tags: c#

how to use property of that control for which toolstrip is attached in itemselect event of that toolstrip in c#.net 3.5?

```
picArray[n].ContextMenuStrip = new ContextMenuStrip();
ToolStripItem Schedule = picArray[n].ContextMenuStrip.Items.Add("Schedule");
picArray[n].ContextMenuStrip.Items.Add("Schedule");
picArray[n].ContextMenuStrip.ItemClicked += (sender, e) =>
            {                                
            panel1.Show();                        
            if (e.ClickedItem == Schedule)
                {
                //Here I want to use property of that picturebox on which right
                //click is done
                }
```

Comment: I just have a question...why you create one new ContextMenuStrip for each Control? You can associate the same one to more than one control...

Comment: @Adriano: I have four picturebox for 4 device all picturebox name is given ipaddress string of corresponding device.now by right clicking a picturebox i want to access that device and for that I will need that IP address which is stored picArray.Name.

Comment: You may create just one ContextMenuStrip and assign it to all of them. The SourceControl property will always hold the control that generated the ItemClicked event.

Comment: @Adriano: ok I think your style will occupy memory of my program I will try it. Thanks !

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try something like:

```
var contextMenuStrip = (ContextMenuStrip) e.ClickedItem.GetCurrentParent();
var pictureBox = (PictureBox) contextMenuStrip.SourceControl;
pictureBox. //here you can access it.
```

This code doesn't check if casts are valid.

Comment: Thanks dude This is as I wanted!